# Why we use blocks in objective C instead of functions?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Can anyone tell me why we use blocks instead of functions and methods as three can perform the same work. Then what is the necessity to use blocks..And is there any types of blocks ??

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=lambda+functions

Comment: I read this but cant understand @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: @NishaGupta: Blocks has many advantages, few of them 1.Used as completion/callback. 2.Works beyond its scope. 3.Can be used as properties.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Can u explain in detail its neccesity

Comment: @Hemang Not sure this question is solely focused on `iOS` this could also include `OSX`, I don't believe your edit is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blocks, sometimes called anonymous functions, are really nothing more than functions with state.  Sometimes that state is what makes them particularly useful, and sometimes we use them solely for convenience of syntax and conciseness of code.

When a block captures state, it's called a closure.  This means that variables defined outside of the block's scope, but used within the block, are captured at the point the block is defined.  That is, when the code which defines the block is executed at runtime.  This means that each execution of the block can (and often will) capture different values for the same variables.

Comment: Can u elaborate more

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  Blocks are great for callbacks, and there are tons of APIs built around them.  They are also good for keeping code together, so you don't have to create a one-off function to be used in one place.  In short: it's (sometimes) a matter of style, and that's it.

Comment: Types OF Block are ?? @Avi

Comment: Also, some functions need to delegate some task or offer the option to perform a custom task as part of/at the end of _their_ task (e.g., completion handlers). That's where blocks as arguments to methods comes handy.

Comment: @NicolasMiari can u elaborate more how many types of passing arguments?

Comment: Not really. I can't make it more explicit than what I or Avi have already explained.